# How do I hide grease pencil strokes behind the mesh in render

Tags: grease-pencil

[image: screenshot of grease pencil stroke in front of mesh]

---

In the above image the back scrambling is just for showing purposes

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

nvm found it . just neded to enable the z pass

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/701145948126052404/931642658366062592/unknown.png